# List in RecyclerView is not updating when List is changed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Why is it that my list in RecyclerView does not update when I add a new object into the list? I have used DiffUtil and placed a break point in the implemented methods and I get an updated value in the `differ.submitList(value)` but not in the "diffcallback".
In the first instance I create the List, I get no issues but when I add another element to the List, it does not reflect. Please see my RecyclerView Adapter

```kotlin
    class VehiclesInvolvedAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<VehiclesInvolvedAdapter.VehiclesInvolvedViewHolder>(){
        inner class VehiclesInvolvedViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    
        private val diffCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<VehicleInformation>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(
                oldItem: VehicleInformation,
                newItem: VehicleInformation
            ): Boolean {
                return oldItem.id == newItem.id
            }
    
            override fun areContentsTheSame(
                oldItem: VehicleInformation,
                newItem: VehicleInformation
            ): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }
        }
    
        private val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, diffCallback)
        var vehicleInformationList: List<VehicleInformation>
        get() = differ.currentList
        set(value) {
            differ.submitList(value)
        }
    
    
    
        override fun getItemCount() = differ.currentList.size
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VehiclesInvolvedViewHolder {
            return VehiclesInvolvedViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                    R.layout.item_vehicle_involved,
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VehiclesInvolvedViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val vehicleInformation = vehicleInformationList[position]
    
            holder.itemView.apply {
                var btnVehicle = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.btnVehicle)
                btnVehicle.text = vehicleInformation.plateNumber
    
                setOnClickListener {
                    onItemClickListener?.let { it(vehicleInformation) }
                }
            }
        }
    
        private var onItemClickListener: ((VehicleInformation) -> Unit)? = null
    
        fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (VehicleInformation) -> Unit) {
            onItemClickListener = listener
        }
    }

    // This is how I add another object to the List
    private fun setupRecyclerView() = binding!!.rvVehicleInvolved.apply {
        vehicleInvolvedAdapter = VehiclesInvolvedAdapter()
        adapter = vehicleInvolvedAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
    }
    
    private fun addOBject() {
        vehicleInformationList.add(vehicleInformation)
        vehicleInvolvedAdapter.vehicleInformationList = vehicleInformationList => THIS IS SUPPOSED TO UPDATE THE ITEMS IN THE RECYCLERVIEW
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not notifying the adapter of the change made in the list, checkout the variety of notify functions in the documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter) and pick the most suitable one. I'll assume that the new list is completely different from the previous one and offer you this change:

```
private fun addOBject() {
    vehicleInformationList.add(vehicleInformation)
    vehicleInvolvedAdapter.vehicleInformationList = vehicleInformationList
    vehicleInvolvedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

I recommend that you don't use notifyDataSetChanged() due to performance issues on larger lists, instead use notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) to update only the items that were added or changed.

Answer (score 3):

1. you add new element to the list
2. you notify that the list had changed
3. differ compares the "new" list with the "old" list
4. it's same instance in both cases, so there can't be any differences -> no update

You've basically circumvented the differ by sneakily modifying its list.

As a quick hack you can use:

```
set(value) {
    differ.submitList(value.toList()) //makes a copy
}
```

But you really need to rethink how lists work. Immutability is the way to prevent such problems.

Also, the code you've posted is missing something: `vehicleInformationList.add` shouldn't be possible, because the list is immutable. Immutability is preserved with `vehicleInformationList = vehicleInformationList.plus(vehicleInformation)`

Answer (score 1):

The `vehicleInvolvedAdapter` needs to be notified every time the `vehicleInformationList` is updated. Replace your `addOBject` function with the following:

```
private fun addOBject() {
    vehicleInformationList.add(vehicleInformation)
    vehicleInvolvedAdapter.vehicleInformationList = vehicleInformationList 
    vehicleInvolvedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Read the following link: [Adapters](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter)